# How to host an MSIX package for url installation of a WinForms desktop app

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, desktop-application, installation-package, msix

I created an MSIX package for a WinForms desktop application using the Visual Studio Windows Application Packaging Project Wizzard with below settings:

sideloading, automatic updates enabled, installer location from url

I copied the package (all files) to a hosted website sub-folder (whose domain I own) but I do not know how to make the package available for installation on client desktops (i.e: give my clients a link to the package where they can start the installation). The package includes an Index.html which I tested by adding its url into the browser address field, but I got

```
The website cannot be reached
```

So I figured, that I need to host a small website with a download link that points to the Index.html.
But I wonder if there is a shorter/simpler approach - any help will be appreciated to point me to a more simple approach than hosting an entire website.

Answer (score 1):

You need to leverage the [appinstaller file](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/ms-appinstaller-protocol.html) built by Visual Studio next to your MSIX package.

In the linked article above we explain how the appinstaller file works with a small example.

Here are also more details about configuring [auto-updates for sideloaded MSIX packages](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-auto-updates.html).